# Get returned value of function in function which called it

Tags: python

I am newbie in python, and I build two functions in which, I am calling `second function` with  `1 parameters` in first function and I am trying to access `second function's returned data` in first function.

```
def second_function(first_param):
    final = first_param + 50
    return final

def first_function():
    second_function(50)
    # trying to access second_function's returned data HERE
    print(second_function)
```

But it is not showing any returned data.

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance.

Comment: You need to store the result of the call... `result = second_fuction(50)` and then `print(result)` ?

Comment: If you're new to Python, a good place to start is [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), not Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using `print(second_function)`, so that will simply output the name of the **function**. Now, if you want to output the **result** of the function, you should do:

```
def second_function(first_param):
    final = first_param + 50
    return final

def first_function():
    output = second_function(50)
   
    print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could first put the returned value in a variable like this

```
def second_function(first_param):
    final = first_param + 50
    return final

def first_function():
    value = second_function(60)
    print(value )
```

or print the returned value with out using any variable

```
def second_function(first_param):
    final = first_param + 50
    return final

def first_function():
    print(second_function(50))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `second_function` is an object in its own right. Try either of the following:

```py
def first_function():
    out = second_function(50)
    # trying to access second_function's returned data HERE
    print(out)

def first_function_alternate():
    print(second_function(50))
```

What's happening when you do `print(second_function)` is that the computer is trying to print the value of the function itself, not what it returns. We can store this value to a variable (my first answer) or simply generate it on-the-fly (my second answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Python, the returned data from a function will be assigned to a *variable*. So you would use:

```py
my_value = second_function(60)
```

and the returned value would be stored in the variable `my_value`